# Case When Statements

Tags: sql

I'm fairly new to SQL (~ 4 months) and trying to replace an outdated report to which I don't have access to the underlying SQL code. In attempting to replace it I've built the below as a test, but am getting an error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

When I remove the two AS statements, I get an error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'. Am I overlooking something very basic here? I'm still learning about CASE statements, but I believe I'm using a Case Searched format here correctly to allow for the boolean WHEN statement. Thanks in advance.

```
DECLARE @DATE AS DATETIME
SET @Date=GETDATE()

SELECT
j.team_name
, r.contractname
, r.contracttype
, r.requisitiontype
, r.reason
, r.hm
, j.city_name
, j.state_name
, j.positionid
, r.nci_job_title
, r.recruiter
, j.created_datetime
, DATEDIFF(d,j.created_datetime,@Date
, r.anticipatedstartdate
, DATEDIFF(d,@Date,r.anticipatedstartdate)
, CASE 
    WHEN c.hiring_status_desc = 'Applicant Submittal' AND DATEDIFF(d,@Date,c.DateCreated) < 7 THEN COUNT(c.DateCreated) 
    ELSE 0 
END AS 'SubmittalsThisWeek'
, CASE 
    WHEN c.hiring_status_desc = 'Applicant Submittal' THEN COUNT(c.DateCreated)
    ELSE 0 
END AS 'TotalSubmittals'

--Add more cases

FROM tblrequisition r

JOIN tbljobs j 
    ON r.positionid = j.positionid

JOIN tbl candidateinterviewstat c 
    ON r.requisition_id = c.requisition_id

WHERE r.[requsition status] = 'Open'
AND r.positionid > 1000000

GROUP BY
j.team_name
, r.contractname
, r.contracttype
, r.requisitiontype
, r.reason
, r.hm
, j.city_name
, j.state_name
, j.positionid
, r.nci_job_title
, r.recruiter
, j.created_datetime
, DATEDIFF(d,j.created_datetime,@Date)
, r.anticipatedstartdate
, DATEDIFF(d,@Date,r.anticipatedstartdate)
```

Comment: You forgot a `)` here: `DATEDIFF(d,j.created_datetime,@Date` and `JOIN tbl candidateinterviewstat c ` is not correct ...

Comment: Thanks! That plus one other fix I found got me there.